# How to display SQL Server CE data correctly in a View C# MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, layout, razor

I'm in need of some help in getting a View to layout data it is accessing from a database correctly.

I have a simple View on my MVC3 c# site to display the data stored in a database. The View code is below:

```
<div id="content" class="valign">
    <p>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                <i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.News_Date)</i><br />        
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.News_Entry)<br />
            <br />
        }
    </p>
</div>
```

This works fine initially, the data is displayed as shown below:

```
Date <br>
Post

Date <br>
Post

Date <br>
Post 

...etc
```

The issue I have now is that when viewing the "Post" data using the method above it doesn't include carriage returns, so paragraphs etc are not displayed correctly with line breaks.

I received some help earlier from people on this site on how to achieve a bit of formatting when displaying typing data into a TextArea box and uploading it to a database, then displaying that data (including line breaks) on a separate page View. The method they gave me to display this data is below:

```
@foreach (var data in Model)
{                       
    @Html.Raw(data.News_Entry.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"))
}
```

This preserved line-breaks that were used in the original data input.

However, now if I want to display data I have to use this method to display the "date":

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.News_Date)</i><br /> 
}
```

...and this method to display the "post":

```
@foreach (var data in Model)
{
    @Html.Raw(data.News_Entry.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"))
}
```

...but it doesn't display the data on the page like before, i.e:

```
Date <br>
Post
```

It displays it as:

```
Date <br>
Date <br>
Date <br>
 <br>
Post <br>
Post <br>
Post <br>
```

Would anyone please be able to help me get around this?

Preferably, I'd like to have the Date displayed first, and the post displayed underneath it, whilst keeping linebreaks intact.

To maybe illustrate a bit better, I have a couple of screenshots:

[Correct way to display](http://www.zen87038.zen.co.uk/image/correct.jpg) 
[Incorrect way to display](http://www.zen87038.zen.co.uk/image/incorrect.jpg)

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you try this? @foreach (var data in Model)
{@Html.Raw(data.News_Entry.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>")<i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelData => data.News_Date)</i>}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appologies for wasting the boards time - I managed to sort it out myself by adding the News_Date like below:

```
<p>
    @foreach (var data in Model)
    {
        <i>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => data.News_Date)</i><br />
        @Html.Raw(data.News_Entry.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>"))<br />
    }
</p>
```

Comment: Sorry Pabloker - I think I posted that at the same time as yours, your answer would also work fine - thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use [HTML pre tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)?

> The pre tag defines preformatted text.
>
> Text in a pre element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually
>   Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we tried the <pre> tag before, and it didn't display correctly with the desired font and size etc.

Comment: @Harry just a tiny bit of css would help you in that.

Comment: Thanks Archil - I didn't think of over-riding it with CSS - so I assume it's all ok to set width's / fonts etc for <pre> tag? The other issue I had was widths were all out - but if that solves it then bham - issue solved (again!) :-)

Comment: The css is there to solve all the problems / issues with displaying content. :)